# Need a script to convert comma delimited files to tab delimited

Tags: unix, sh

Could you please help me with converting the comma separated file into tab separated file?

from
"1","a","me,and,you"

to
1         a        me,and,you

use unix script

Answer (score 1):

*file.csv:*

```
"1","a","me,and,you"
```

*convertFile.sh*

```
 #!/bin/bash
    IFS=","
    while read f1 f2
    do
            echo -e $f1\t$f2
    done <  file.csv
```